# Jest test `expect().toThrowError()` passes but still logs an uncaught error to the console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using Jest and react-testing-library to test a "modal" component in a "portal" that needs to me mounted to a DOM node. This DOM node is configurable but defaults to `body`. To get proper test coverage I pass it a bad value too, which should lead to an Error. I'm trying to assert this happens and catch the Error by using the `expect().toThrowError()` API, this works just fine. However, in the logs I still see an uncaught error printed. I think this maybe caused by the React library printing it before raising the same exception again, but that doesn't mean I can prevent it I guess.

I could just return a fallback error message, in the UI, but I feel like this is not how this should work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or even a suggestion to just take an entirely different approach?

```js
// modal.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export interface ModalProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  DOMNodeSelector?: string;
}

export const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({
  children,
  DOMNodeSelector = 'body',
}) => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('modal-wrapper');

  // Mount and unmount the modal in the portal
  useEffect(() => {
    const portal = document.querySelector(DOMNodeSelector);
    if (!portal)
      throw new Error(`Querying "${DOMNodeSelector}" did not yield a DOM node`);
    portal.appendChild(wrapper);
    return () => {
      portal.removeChild(wrapper);
    };
  }, []);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div className="modal">{children}</div>,
    wrapper,
  );
};
```

```js
//modal.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import {Modal} from './modal';

describe('<Modal>', () => {
it(`throws an Error when passed a bad dom node selector`, () => {
    expect(() => {
      render(
        <Modal DOMNodeSelector=".badselector">Hello World!</Modal>,
      );
    }).toThrowError(/did not yield a dom node/i);
  });
});
export default Modal;
```

```
console.error
    Error: Uncaught [Error: Querying ".badselector" did not yield a DOM node]
        at reportException (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:333:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23574:9)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/scheduler@0.20.1/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:646:12) Error: Querying ".badselector" did not yield a DOM node
        at /workspaces/project/src/modal.tsx:20:13
        at invokePassiveEffectCreate (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23487:20)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
        at invokeEventListeners (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23574:9)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/scheduler@0.20.1/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:646:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
        at flushPassiveEffects (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23447:14)
        at Object.<anonymous>.flushWork (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:992:10)
        at act (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1107:9)
        at render (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library/react@11.2.5_react-dom@17.0.1+react@17.0.1/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:95:26)
        at /workspaces/project/src/modal.test.tsx:8:7
        at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/expect@26.6.2/node_modules/expect/build/toThrowMatchers.js:83:11)
        at Object.toThrowError (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/expect@26.6.2/node_modules/expect/build/index.js:338:21)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/project/src/modal.test.tsx:11:8)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-jasmine2@26.6.3/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-jasmine2@26.6.3/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-jasmine2@26.6.3/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /workspaces/project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-jasmine2@26.6.3/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at reportException (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:28)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:333:9)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.4.0/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)

  console.error
    The above error occurred in the <Modal> component:
    
        at Modal (/workspaces/project/src/modal.tsx:10:3)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20085:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20118:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12318:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12339:9)
      at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20736:11)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23426:7)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@17.0.1_react@17.0.1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
```

Comment: If you simply want the error log not to show during your test you could mock it before your assertion: `jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});`.